# Can I skip DS9, Season 1 entirely?

Tags: star-trek, suggested-order, star-trek-ds9

I started Deep Space Nine : Season 1, Episode 1 and I found it boring

Based on that, I'm debating whether to skip season 1 and jump to season 2. Are there any episodes in Season 1 that are **essential viewing**,  in order to understand what's happening in later series?

Comment: Although I've made my point about minimum recommended viewing orders here http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4841/why-are-minimum-viewing-guides-considered-off-topic, I'm still VTC because this isn't really a recommended viewing order; you seem to merely be asking whether or not DS9 becomes less boring or not!

Comment: I'm editing it to be less opinion-based, but still should answer the OP's core question.  It's now basically the same as a Fringe one we had, which didn't get any VTCs.  user31149, feel free to roll it back or make your own edits if I'm thinking wrong

Comment: I've edited further. "If I skip X, will I understand Y?" seems a lot less subjective.

Comment: DS9 was really all about the Dominion wars, if you want to follow this main story arc, then the first episode is the finale of Season 2 "Jem'hadar". It pretty much ramps up from then on out.

Comment: @Jared First mention of the Dominion was actually in [Rules of Acquisition](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Rules_of_Acquisition_(episode)).  By skipping ahead to the action you do miss some worthwhile stuff.

Comment: The two-part premiere was probably a bit too much for one episode, but not quite enough for a decently paced two-parter, hence the slowness. But almost everything in it is setup for future stories and character development. Being set predominantly on a station which by and large doesn't go anywhere, most of the stories generally don't have the same sort of action-adventure pacing as the other ship-centric shows (TOS, TNG, VOY, ENT), but they are still a good watch.

Comment: Wow, _one_ episode and you want to skip the season. Why bother watching TV at all if your attention span is that short?

Comment: I believe DS9 to be about the characters and their journey, more so than any of the other series. Every relationship at the end of DS9 has been drastically altered from how they began. The obvious example would be Miles & Julian end the run with a long "buddy episode" a vastly different scenario than their interaction in Season One episodes.  Season One may not be considered GREAT to some but it is the foundation of this series because it is the BEFORE picture.  After re-watching the entire series recently I would also note that there is much more in S1 that comes back than you might realize.

Answer (score 11):

[Season 1 of DS9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine_episodes#Season_1_.281993.29) is generally considered to be quite weak. There were a number of episodes that, whilst fun for hardened trekkies were basically "monster of the week" shows that contributed very little to the overall plot arc.

As far as 'essential' episodes are concerned, As a minimum you'll want to watch:

- **Episode 1+2 : Emmissary** - In which we're introduced to the majority of the main characters
- **Episode 3: Past Prologue** - In which we learn about the history of the Cardassian/Bajoran conflict.
- **Episode 13 - Battle Lines** - More essential Bajoran political/religious background info
- **Episode 19 - Duet** - Great big chunks of backstory for the Cardassian occupation.
- **Episode 20 - In the Hands of the Prophets** - Setting up the three-parter at the start of season 2.

---

Episode 10 (Move Along Home), Episode 11 (The Nagus), Episode 7 (Q-Less) and Episode 6 (Captive Pursuit) are all excellent episodes in their own right, but not really *essential* to future plotlines unless you're a hardcore Ferenghi/O'Brien/Q fan.

Comment: *Move Along Home*? Yikes, I thought that was a clunker.

Comment: @pauld.waite - Yes, but it's quite highly rated by fans. Also, it gives us insight into quark's character.

Comment: Several character arcs are launched in some of the season 1 episodes and further advanced in later seasons (or at least events/relationships get a revisit): ep #8 "Dax", #11 "The Nagus" (Quark), #17 "The Forsaken" (Odo and Lwaxana).

Comment: I disagree about Q-Less - that seemed to me to be yet another season 1 episode where they were stuck in the trappings and shadow of TNG.  I'm also not a fan of most of the Ferengi-centric episodes since they all seemed to just be gimmicky.

Comment: @AnthonyX - It's perfectly possible to skip most/all of the Dax, Odo and Quark episodes and miss very little of show's main plot.

Comment: @Richard - agreed; while the episodes I mention were likely written as stand alone and don't contribute to the overall Dominion, Bajoran, and Cardassian story arcs, the characters and character life events are revisited in later seasons. Those later episodes make more sense with the season 1 character "backstories" in place.

Comment: @anthonyx - Yes. Odo grows in importance as it becomes clear what his connection is to the leaders of the Dominion. You can happily miss all his earlier episodes though.

Answer (score 5):

I would say watch them all. Remember it's not a race to the end, it's the journey. There are tidbits of character introduction and development worth seeing and that add to the overall tapestry. Some interesting situations can be had even in the midst of some bad writing.